# SurrealDB - How to get RELATE contents?

Tags: relation, surrealdb

I have three tables, `Product`, `Bought`, `User`.

I set relations like this:

```
RELATE User:1->Bought->Product:1
    SET amount = 1;
```

If I run a query like this `SELECT ->Bought->Product as bought FROM User:1` the results are only the id's of the bought products like this:

```
[
    {
        "bought": [
            "Product:1",
            "Product:3",
            "Product:8",
        ]
    }
]
```

Then I need to access the Product's properties and the query will be `SELECT ->Bought->Product.* as bought FROM User:1` and the results:

```
[
    {
        "bought": [
            {
                "id": "Product:1",
                "name": "Chocolate"
            },
            {
                "id": "Product:3",
                "name": "Bread"
            },
            {
                "id": "Product:8",
                "name": "Milk"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

But I need to attributes of **"Bought" RELATION** too like this:

```
[
    {
        "bought": [
            {
                "id": "Product:1",
                "name": "Chocolate",
                "amount": 5
            },
            {
                "id": "Product:3",
                "name": "Bread",
                "amount": 2
            },
            {
                "id": "Product:8",
                "name": "Milk",
                "amount": 1
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

**How can I append the RELATE content of the relation between two tables as in last example?**

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *, (SELECT *,out.* AS product FROM ->bought) AS bought FROM person;
```

You can use this. I know it is not exactly as you want. but you can get all users with bought array which contain all information of purchase.

If you need only list of bought you can try this.

```
 SELECT *,in.* AS person,out.* AS product from bought;
```